# How to move yoke in the vertical axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to move an airplane yoke in the vertical axis.  I am using the mouse pointer to move yoke in vertical axis up and down and clamped the value.  When I run the script the yoke is positioned some ever and not moving up and down.  The yoke is not moving up and down.  How to move yoke up and down as shown in the image using below code.

[image: yoke]

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  namespace plane
  {
 public class IP_AirplaneThrottle_Physical : MonoBehaviour
  {
    #region Variables
    public float maxZOffset = -0.5f;
    public float sensitivity = 0.001f;
    public float smoothSpeed = 8f;

    public bool isHitting = false;
    public float wantedDelta;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 wantedPos;
    private Vector2 lastMousePosition;
    #endregion


    #region Builtin Methods
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //Get the lever starting position
        startPos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        HandleRaycast();
        HandleInteraction();
    }
    #endregion



    #region Custom Methods
    void HandleRaycast()
    {
        //Build a ray so we can see if we are hitting the lever
        Ray curRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        //Do our Raycast into the scene
        if(Physics.Raycast(curRay, out hit, 1000f))
        {
            if(hit.transform.GetInstanceID() == this.transform.GetInstanceID())
            {
                Debug.Log("Hitting the Lever!");
                if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                {
                    //We are hitting so get the start mouse position
                    isHitting = true;
                    lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
                    print ("123");
                }
            }
        }

        //If we let go of the left mouse button then stop everything
        if(isHitting && Input.GetMouseButton(0) == false)
        {
            isHitting = false;
        }
    }

    void HandleInteraction()
    {
        if(isHitting)
        {
            //Calculate the delta for Z offset
            wantedDelta = (lastMousePosition.y - Input.mousePosition.y) * Time.deltaTime * sensitivity;
            startPos.z += wantedDelta;

            //make sure we dont go to far
            startPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(startPos.z, maxZOffset, 0f);
            wantedPos = startPos;

            //Get the New Mouse Position every frame while we are holding
            lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;



        }
        else
        {
            //Clear out the Delta value
            wantedDelta = 0f;
        }
                //Move the lever

             transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, wantedPos, Time.deltaTime * smoothSpeed);


    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: I would only do a raycast if you press the mouse button. 
You forgot to write the code after: //Move the lever